# How to run multiple browsers instance with Webdriver, Java and Junit/TestNG?

Tags: java, junit, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have a test ready to be executed but it takes a long time to finish. In this test I'm feeding in csv data, so basically the whole test will run 56 times. I was wondering if there's anyway I could use multiple browser instance and divide the workload to four instance. It will save me some time. I tried to use TestNG's ThreadPoolSize but it's not doing what I want it to. It's using the same data for four instances of firefox. I want each browser to have it's own unique data. Please check my code and let me know what I'm missing. I really appriciate every one's help.

```
public class StudentPageTest {
WebDriver driver;
DesiredCapabilities capability; 
WebElement element;
WebDriverWait wait;
private String baseURL;

@BeforeTest
public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException{
    //capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    //driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    //wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 120);
    //driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    baseURL = "http://somewebsite.com";

}
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
@Test(threadPoolSize = 4)
public void StudentPortalTest() throws InterruptedException, IOException{
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 120);
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    String studentId = "studentID.csv";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";

    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(studentId));
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] student_id = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

        //Logging in Student Portal---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
        for (int i = 0; i < student_id.length; i++) {       
            driver.get(baseURL+student_id[i]);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".logo>img")).isDisplayed();
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#UserName")).sendKeys("SecretUserName");
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#Password")).sendKeys("EvenMoreSecretPassword");
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".submitBtn")).click();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            Thread.sleep(4000);
           ...............and the test goes on below................... 
    }
@AfterTest
public void tearDown(){
    driver.quit();
    }
 }
```

Comment: I think TestNG's `threadPoolSize` is not what you think it is. I believe it's meant to test multi-thread safety by executing the same test from multiple threads, not lighten the load of the method. So I assume you'll probably have to implement some self-made multi-thread solution. You can start by creating a method that splits all the lines in `studentID.csv` into 4 pieces, then you could create multiple threads and assign each to run the method with its own piece of the CSV.

Answer (score 0):

You can let the [Selenium grid](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2) do the task of distribution.  Use TestNG to run your cases in parallel using dataprovider. Use a [dataprovider](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders) to read your csv and pass one data to one @Test. 
Set dataprovider thread count in your suite xml and make sure you set `@DataProvider(parallel=true)`

Going to your code, replace your call of instantiating a firefoxdriver to remotewebdriver to use the grid.  Make sure your driver is not at class level but is a  [threadlocal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) : `threadlocal<driver>`.

Comment: Neo(cool name)-- is there anyway you could provide some example code please? I have never used @DataProvider :(

Answer (score 0):

I was trying many different ways to achieve the same thing you are trying to do. After a lot of trial and error I finally came across a solution that worked for me.

1. You need [Selenium Grid](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2)  You can then set up a few nodes to run your different browsers from
2. You need TestNG like you have been using but instead of trying to use threads, you will use an .xml file to pass in parameters to your test which will run the one test over and over in parallel.

If you read [this](https://www.packtpub.com/sites/default/files/downloads/Distributed_Testing_with_Selenium_Grid.pdf) document carefully and follow the steps, you should be able to achieve the same result

Comment: it would be really helpful if you would address the question and the code from the initial post

Answer (score 0):

@Test(threadPoolSize = 4, invocationCount = 4)

Comment: Perhaps you can provide a more detailed answer? E.g. elaborate a bit on how this answers the question, if there are any considerations to take into account, where does this code should take place etc.